# How can this be a number?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can this be considered a number?

```
<cfquery name="test">
   SELECT ISNUMERIC("8D4") AS isnum
</cfquery>
```

this returns 1.

Are there other checks I need to perform?

Comment: One word: "HexaDecimal".

Comment: It might be a word, but it's got nothing to do with the answer.

Comment: @AdamCameron Yep, it's an archaic scientific notation format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`D` and `E` are considered special cases for `isNumeric()`. `E` is easily demonstrated to reflect scientific notation:

```
SELECT ISNUMERIC('8E4'), 8E4
```

Results in:

```
1    80000
```

The case with `D` is different. Many resources on the web describe it as a [form of denoting decimal numbers](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic472175-9-1.aspx), or [just a form of scientific notation](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/1/justlearned/0/tips/14894/what-is-wrong-with-isnumeric.aspx).

One gets odd behaviour if altering my SQL above to use `D` instead though:

```
SELECT  8E4, 8D4
```

In SQL Studio, this results in:

```
(No column Name)    D4
80000              8
```

I am not a SQL expert (of any stripe: I'm just a CFML developer), but this suggests to me that the description of `D` before for decimals or S/N is not the full story.

But whatever the story is, it's well-documented that the form `nDn` (where `n` are digits) is `TRUE` to `ISNUMERIC()`.

Comment: You're right, it's not hexadecimal as I thought.  It's an archaic form of scientific notation that I had forgotten about.  It's effectively the same as `8E4`.  The odd behavior that you are seeing has to do with a legacy parsing limitation (possibly bug) of SQL when trying to separate numeric literals from column aliases without a space, but it doesn't really have anything to do with why `8D4` is a number.  To see what number it is, try `SELECT CAST('8D4' As Float)` instead.

Comment: Ah! I tried using `DECIMAL` and got an error. Wish I'd tried `FLOAT` first!

Answer (score 0):

Your Parameter contains `D` which is hexadecimal.
`8D4` (in hex) is `2260` (in decimal)

So it is a valid number, that's why 1 will be returned.

Comment: If this was true, then `8A4`, `8F4` would also be numeric, yes? But they're not. Did you *check* this answer before posting it?